# Using RenderAction to render a user control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my input form I let user select a state. List of the states is stored in the database (because we do not support every state yet). This list changes very infrequently.

So I want to use `RenderAction` to render the control, simply because I do not want to pass list of states with every ViewModel to the view. The result of this action is a drop down.

Since this is an input control it needs to have a name. So from my main view I call RenderAction as follows:

```
@Html.RenderAction("GetStates", "Data", new { controlName = "states" });
```

passing `controlName` does not feel right. I feels like I am misusing `RenderAction` to create a user control, and `@Html.Partial` would be more appropriate, on the other hand I do not want to pass list of states to the `@Html.Partial` because that piece of information is more relevant to presentation concern.

**Question** should I stick with RenderAction and pass controlName as described above? or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with passing controlname as a param. i would go with that.

In addition, the list of states you get from the database. If you are displaying this list multiple times on the page... Store it in TempData. If exists in tempdata, retrieve and use it saving a database hit. You could even cache it up higher.

Comment: That's the intent, using RenderAction lets me use Cache attribute out of the box.

Comment: hmm, i would look into that. Last i heard you cannot use Cache Attr with partial views. As in, it wont cache

Comment: My bad, [OutputCache(Duration = 3600)] not Cache attr